# Server on java does not get message from Qt client

Tags: java, qt, server, client, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have very simple java server:

```
int port = 2245;
       try {
         ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
         System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

         Socket incomingClient = ss.accept();
         InputStream i = incomingClient.getInputStream();
         OutputStream o = incomingClient.getOutputStream();  // Use it write to the Client Socket
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
         String str = new String();

         while ((str = br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("str = " + str);
                o.write(123); //("message from server");
          }
       } catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
```

And I have simple Qt client, that use QNetworkAccessManager

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl url("http://127.0.0.1:2245");
url.port(6666);
QByteArray postData;
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QString postKey("SomeKey");
postData.append(postKey);
QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
```

I declared in mainwindow.h in slot replyFinished

```
public slots: 
void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);
```

In best case Server get some headers like(POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded and others)

But on server I can not read my message from client
and client does not receive ANY response from java server

Comment: Are you using port 2245 or 6666? It can only be one or the other, not both.

Comment: I am using 2245 port everywhere, sorry if it confused you
Server see the qt client and even get some data, but I can not get any response on Qt client from java server

Comment: In that case, what's up with this line: `url.port(6666);`

Comment: I have just set everywhere in code port 2245 and it is still does not work correctly, client side totally does want  to get message from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for Qt client is this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QUrl url("http://192.168.0.101:8000");
url.port(8000);

QByteArray postData;
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QString postKey("some data");
postData.append(postKey);
QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

manager->post(request, postData);
```

}

and to get response declare and implement the following slot

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
qDebug() << "Status" << reply->errorString();
qDebug() << "Status" << reply->error();


     QByteArray data = reply->readAll(); //It's works!
     qDebug() << "data: " << data;
```

}

For server side I have used HttpServer, which is available in latest version of JDK